# "Event driven" static webpage updates

Tags: static, static-pages

I get that by the very nature of static web pages, their content is, well, "static". In a world though where it's becoming ever more popular to host static pages on a service like AWS S3 and run some cloud computing functionality through something like AWS Lambda, I was wondering if it was possible to update your static content when something were to change, making your sites less static.

Sure, you can send out Ajax calls every second or so to see if anything changed, but in my humble opinion, that seems stupid and not really like a viable option.

Say for instance I kick off a process from my static page that will write an entry into a key store database when the process completed. Is there a way to update the web page to let the user know the process has finished, without reloading the page?

Comment: Have you browsed the [server-push] tag?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't look like this will work in a server-less setup, since from what I've read so far you need a server to persist the connection to the client.